# Scrapy yields items to DB with /u

Tags: python, scrapy, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am running a spider that saves data to DynamoDB. I've been looking through StackOverflow for an answer but couldn't find. It saves `stamp` and `title` to DynamoDB with all different characters like /u and brackets. `url` are saved properly, without extra characters. How can I make it save without them?

My spider:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for item in response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'river-block')]"):
        url = item.xpath(".//h2[@class='post-title']/a/@href").extract()[0]
        stamp = item.xpath(".//time/@datetime").extract()
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details, meta={'stamp': stamp})

def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
        article['url'] = format(shortener.short(response.url))
        article['stamp'] = response.meta['stamp']
        yield article
```

My pipelines file:

```
class DynamoDBStorePipeline(object):

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb',region_name="us-west-2")

    table = dynamodb.Table('TechCrunch')

    table.put_item(
    Item={
    'url': str(item['url']),
    'title': str(item['title']),
    'stamp': str(item['stamp']),
    }
    )
    return item
```

Sample output:
url : a link (it's fine)
stamp: [u'2017-05-17 08:06:47']
title: [u'title']

Comment: please provide sample values of `title`, `sample` and `url` and expected output, also the site url you are trying to scrap.

Comment: use `extract_first()` instead of `extract()`, if this doesn't solve your problem, provide update post with link you are scraping.

Comment: @JkShaw worked like a charm. Thank you sir. Can you please write it up as an aswer so I can upvote and accept your answer?

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Scrapy` one can use `extract` to get `textual data`, but If you want to `extract` only `first matched element`, you can call the selector `extract_first()`.

In your case update `stamp` and `title` selector needs to be `extract_first()` as follows:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for item in response.xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'river-block')]"):
        url = item.xpath(".//h2[@class='post-title']/a/@href").extract_first()
        stamp = item.xpath(".//time/@datetime").extract_first()
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.get_details, meta={'stamp': stamp})

def get_details(self, response):
        article = ArticleItem()
        article['title'] = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract_first()
        article['url'] = format(shortener.short(response.url))
        article['stamp'] = response.meta['stamp']
        yield article
```